# como capturar nombre y value de un select sin javascript

Tags: php

```
   <label for="">Codigo Motivo</label>
                        <select required name="cmotivo" class="form-control" id="cmotivo">
                            <option value="01" selected>Anulacion</option>
                            <option value="02">Devolucion</option>
                            <option value="03">Correccion</option>
                            <option value="04">Descuento</option>

                        </select>
```

cuando recibo por post

```
$codigo = $_POST['cmotivo']. $descripcion = $_POST[''] ?
```

Comment: Creería que no es posible, es más un asunto de como funciona HTML. Lo único sería "enmascarar" los dos valores en el atributo value, o tener un array o similar con qué comparar los valores en PHP.

Comment: creo no entiendo lo que pides, se puede saber para que quieres el nombre?

Comment: Como dice @Shaz no es posible, tocaría idear alguna clase de "trampa" (tal y como las que describe @Shaz) para después en php procesar los datos como lo necesitas

Comment: bueno pues tengo esto    ->setCodMotivo('02')
                                 ->setDesMotivo('DEVOLUCION') y como en el select ya tengo los 2 solo queria tomarlos y ponerlos en su respectiva variable

Comment: tendré que hacerlo con condicionales en todo caso

Answer (score 1):

**No es posible**, al menos no de la forma como lo planteas.

---

Al enviar formularios en HTML, de un `<select>` solo se envía el atributo `value` de el o los `<option>` seleccionados.

Tendrías que hacer algún "truco" para no utilizar JavaScript, hay muchas opciones, a continuación muestro dos:

1. Enviar los dos datos "enmascarados" en el atributo `value`, como si fueran serializados:

   ```
   <option value="01-anulacion">Anulacion</option>
   ```

   Ya en PHP se haría el split correspondiente.
2. Tener un array en el backend que reconozca los valores enviados:

   ```
   $valores = ['01' => 'Anulacion', '02' => 'Devolucion', ...
   ```

   Al recibir el o los valores, se obtienen del arreglo los textos.